# How to check if xElement value exists?

Tags: c#, xml, linq, xelement

I need to check  for example if 'Charrizard' exists, I was looking around the web but only found xElement Attribute value and child nodes examples.

```
<pokemons>
  <pokemon>
    <color>red</color>
    <name>Charrizard</name> //the content is named value right ??
  </pokemon>
</pokemons>
```

I saw somewhere it starts like:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("pokemons.xml");
bool b =  doc.Descendants(but don't know how to access the value.)..
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
bool b =  doc.Descendants("name").Any(x=> x.Value == "Charrizard");
```

You achieve that using [**Enumerable.Any**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Determines whether any element of a sequence satisfies a condition.

Here full example in [**dotNetFiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/pL4mus)

Comment: In 'x => x.Value',  'x' represents 'name' ?

Comment: @tomyforever So with doc.Descendants("name") takes all the XElements of your document and put it in IEnumerable collection. If you call doc.Descendants("name").ToList() this will create List<XElement> with TagName name. Method any like I quoted Determines whether any element of a sequence satisfies a condition. So my condition is any element from IEnumerable<XElement> has Value(so the node value) equals to Charrizard return true if not return false. You should probably read what is lambda expression too: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx

Comment: @tomyforever you can mark the question as correct if helped you